# Como crear una cadena json a partir de una clase en php-laravel-livewire

Tags: json, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Estoy intentando crear un json a partir de una clase creada en php y no estoy obteniendo el resultado esperado, les muestro el código que estoy usando y el resultado que obtengo. Desde ya, muchas gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.

Este es la clase que quiero usar:

```
<?php

namespace App\ClasesEspeciales;

Class ClsItemsPed{
    
    private $ProductCode;
    private $SKUCode;
    private $VariantCode;
    private $Description;
    private $VariantDescription;
    private $Quantity;
    private $DiscountPercentage;
    private $UnitPrice;
    private $cantKilos;
    private $SelectMeasureUnit;
    private $MeasureCode;
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->ProductCode = "";
        $this->SKUCode = "";
        $this->VariantCode = "";
        $this->Description = "";
        $this->VariantDescription = "";
        $this->Quantity = "";
        $this->DiscountPercentage = "";
        $this->UnitPrice = "";
        $this->cantKilos = "";
        $this->SelectMeasureUnit = "";
        $this->MeasureCode = "";
    }

    public function getProductCode(){
        return $this->ProductCode;
    }
    public function setProductCode($ProductCode){
        $this->ProductCode = $ProductCode;
    }
    
    public function getSKUCode(){
        return $this->SKUCode;
    }
    public function setSKUCode($SKUCode){
        $this->SKUCode = $SKUCode;
    }
    
    public function getVariantCode(){
        return $this->VariantCode;
    }
    public function setVariantCode($VariantCode){
        $this->VariantCode = $VariantCode;
    }
    
    public function getDescription(){
        return $this->Description;
    }
    public function setDescription($Description){
        $this->Description = $Description;
    }
    
    public function getVariantDescription(){
        return $this->VariantDescription;
    }
    public function setVariantDescription($VariantDescription){
        $this->VariantDescription = $VariantDescription;
    }
    
    public function getQuantity(){
        return $this->Quantity;
    }
    public function setQuantity($Quantity){
        $this->Quantity = $Quantity;
    }
    
    public function getDiscountPercentage(){
        return $this->DiscountPercentage;
    }
    public function setDiscountPercentage($DiscountPercentage){
        $this->DiscountPercentage = $DiscountPercentage;
    }
    
    public function getUnitPrice(){
        return $this->UnitPrice;
    }
    public function setUnitPrice($UnitPrice){
        $this->UnitPrice = $UnitPrice;
    }
    
    public function getcantKilos(){
        return $this->cantKilos;
    }
    public function setcantKilos($cantKilos){
        $this->cantKilos = $cantKilos;
    }
    
    public function getSelectMeasureUnit(){
        return $this->SelectMeasureUnit;
    }
    public function setSelectMeasureUnit($SelectMeasureUnit){
        $this->SelectMeasureUnit = $SelectMeasureUnit;
    }
    
    public function getMeasureCode(){
        return $this->MeasureCode;
    }
    public function setMeasureCode($MeasureCode){
        $this->MeasureCode = $MeasureCode;
    }
}
```

aquí les muestro el código que estoy usando, cabe destacar que es una prueba de funcionalidad, estoy jarcodenado los valores a fin de poder hacer pruebas, después se completará el llenado de la clase con los datos reales.

```
$varPedido = new ClsPedido();

$varPedido->setOrderID('1');
$varPedido->setOrderNumber('1');
$varPedido->setDate('1');
$varPedido->setTotal('1');
$varPedido->setTotalDiscount('1');
$varPedido->setPaidTotal('1');
$varPedido->setFinancialSurcharge('1');
$varPedido->setWarehouseCode('1');
$varPedido->setSellerCode('1');
$varPedido->setTransportCode('1');
$varPedido->setSaleConditionCode('1');
$varPedido->setPriceListNumber('1');
$varPedido->setIvaIncluded('1');
$varPedido->setInternalTaxIncluded('1');
$varPedido->setCancelOrder('1');
$varPedido->setCancelReason('1');
$varPedido->setCancelDate('1');
$varPedido->setAgreedWithSeller('1');
$varPedido->setInvoiceCounterfoil('1');
$varPedido->setComment('1');
$varPedido->setOrderCounterfoil('1');
```

y esta es la línea que estoy usando para generar es json:

```
$json =json_encode(serialize($varPedido));
```

por último, les muestro el resultado que estoy obteniendo y como verán ahí está mi problema:

```
"O:30:\"App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\":23:{s:39:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000OrderID\";s:1:\"1\";s:43:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000OrderNumber\";s:1:\"1\";s:36:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000Date\";s:1:\"1\";s:37:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000Total\";s:1:\"1\";s:45:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000TotalDiscount\";s:1:\"1\";s:41:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000PaidTotal\";s:1:\"1\";s:50:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000FinancialSurcharge\";s:1:\"1\";s:45:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000WarehouseCode\";s:1:\"1\";s:42:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000SellerCode\";s:1:\"1\";s:45:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000TransportCode\";s:1:\"1\";s:49:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000SaleConditionCode\";s:1:\"1\";s:47:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000PriceListNumber\";s:1:\"1\";s:43:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000IvaIncluded\";s:1:\"1\";s:51:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000InternalTaxIncluded\";s:1:\"1\";s:43:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000CancelOrder\";s:1:\"1\";s:44:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000CancelReason\";s:1:\"1\";s:42:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000CancelDate\";s:1:\"1\";s:48:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000AgreedWithSeller\";s:1:\"1\";s:50:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000InvoiceCounterfoil\";s:1:\"1\";s:39:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000Comment\";s:1:\"1\";s:48:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000OrderCounterfoil\";s:1:\"1\";s:42:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000objCliente\";N;s:43:\"\u0000App\\ClasesEspeciales\\ClsPedido\u0000objItemsPed\";N;}"
```

me aparece el path de la clase que esoty usando + algunos caracteres escapados, \u000, en fin, no puedo construir un json limpio.

Desde ya, muchas gracias, saludos y quedo a la espera de vuestros comentarios.

Comment: Tiene que ver con el serializador que estás usando. Si puedes mostrar el código de dicho método tal vez podamos averiguar el problema. Saludos

Comment: Te referías a serialize()?, no es un método mío, está en la documentación de php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es el serializador, tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/533484/como-crear-una-cadena-json-a-partir-de-una-clase-en-php-laravel-livewire?noredirect=1#comment945301_533484).

Si leemos la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php) veremos que el método `serialize`:

> Devuelve una cadena que contiene una representación de flujo de bytes del value que puede ser almacenada en cualquier parte.
>
> Observe que esto es una cadena binaria que puede incluir bytes nulos, y necesita ser almacenada y manipulada como tal. Por ejemplo, la salida de serialize() debe ser generalmente almacenada en un campo de tipo BLOB en la base de datos, en vez de en campos de tipo CHAR o TEXT.

De esto se desprende que con este método no lograrás obtener la cadena JSON que represente los atributos de tu instancia de Clase (objeto).

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, debes crear tu propio serializador que puedes incluir en tu Clase como un método más. Así, podrás llamar a dicho método como uno más del objeto. Eso si, todo atributo que no tenga un valor asignado será tratado como `null`.

Por ejemplo, un método definido en tu Clase puede verse así:

```php
public function toJSON() {
    return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
}
```

Como puedes observar es un serializador muy simple que utiliza dos métodos de PHP:

- [`get_object_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-object-vars.php), que *obtiene las propiedades no estáticas accesibles del objeto dado por `object` según el ámbito.*
- Además, el resultado de `get_object_vars` es un Array asociativo que puede ser codificado a JSON sin problemas por [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)

Para obtener la cadena JSON usando este método, puedes llamar al mismo así:

```php
$my_json = $varPedido->toJSON();
```

Usando una representación de tu Clase, el siguiente código:

```php
<?php

Class ClsItemsPed {
    
    private $ProductCode;
    private $SKUCode;
    private $VariantCode;
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->ProductCode = "";
        $this->SKUCode = "";
        $this->VariantCode = "";
    }

    public function getProductCode(){
        return $this->ProductCode;
    }
    public function setProductCode($ProductCode){
        $this->ProductCode = $ProductCode;
    }
    
    public function getSKUCode(){
        return $this->SKUCode;
    }
    public function setSKUCode($SKUCode){
        $this->SKUCode = $SKUCode;
    }
    
    public function getVariantCode(){
        return $this->VariantCode;
    }
    public function setVariantCode($VariantCode){
        $this->VariantCode = $VariantCode;
    }
    
    public function toJSON() {
        return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}

$varPedido = new ClsItemsPed();

$varPedido->setProductCode("123ABC");
$varPedido->setSKUCode("0123456789012");
$varPedido->setVariantCode("111-2");
$my_json = $varPedido->toJSON();

var_dump($my_json);
```

Produce la siguiente salida:

```
string(72) "{"ProductCode":"123ABC","SKUCode":"0123456789012","VariantCode":"111-2"}"
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: solo funciona en clases con métodos no estáticos y accesibles ... de lo contrario tendría que implementar reflection ... https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.reflectionclass.php

Comment: Eso esta claro en la documentación y en mi respuesta y lo que el OP pide es una forma que le permita convertir los atributos *no estáticos y accesibles de un objeto* a una representación JSON. El código lo hace. Los métodos no pueden convertirse directamente en un valor válido para JSON a menos que se serialicen a `string`. Y para serializar atributos estáticos se puede hacer sin necesidad de usar reflexión, basta un método estático de clase al que llamar.

Answer (score 0):

***Observación***
 esta no es una respuesta estoy agregando un ejemplo en código para aumentar y mejorar la profundidad del análisis que ha expuesto el compañero [@Mauricio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/112837) respuesta que estoy apoyando completamente como valida.

personalmente yo implementaría una clase/método que me permita navegar a través de la recursividad y de la definición de valores:

```php
function my_json_handle($mixed, $depth=512, $recursion=1){
    // recursion limited.
    if($recursion >= $depth){ 
        return print_r($mixed, true);
    }

    //This is a class object data
    if(is_object($mixed)){
    
        //Suppose we encounter datetime data and output it as we want
        if($mixed instanceof DateTime || $mixed instanceof DateTimeImmutable){
            return date_format($mixed, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        //You can customize the processing of more system preset classes here
        
        //First compatible with classes that implement the jsonserialize () method
        if($mixed instanceof JsonSerializable){
            $mixed = $mixed->jsonSerialize();
        }
        elseif(method_exists($mixed, "__json")){
            //Add support for magic method of \
            //My personal feeling is that \
            //Class no longer needs implements jsonserializable
            $mixed = $mixed->__json();
        }
        //Default get object vars() to extract property fields
        if(is_object($mixed)){
            $mixed = get_object_vars($mixed);
        }
        //The above if judgment does not directly return $mixed like datetime
        //Because it is possible to get an iterative data, we need to do iterative processing again
    }
    //Iterative nested data
    if(is_array($mixed)){
        foreach($mixed as $k=>$v){
            //Current iteration level + 1
            $mixed[$k] = my_json_handle($v, $depth, $recursion+1);
        }
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```

Ejemplo implementacion:

```php
class A {
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public $datetime;
    public function __construct($a, $b){
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        $this->datetime = date_create("now",  new DateTimeZone('+0800'));
    }
    public function sum(){
        return $this->a + $this->b;
    }
    
    //You only need to implement the \
    public function __json(){
        //Define the fields we need
        return array(
            "datetime"=>$this->datetime,
            "timestamp"=>$this->datetime->getTimestamp(),
            "sum"=>$this->sum()
        );
    }
}

echo my_json_encode(new A(1,2));
```

output:

> {"datetime":"2019-12-17 16:34:15", "timestamp":1576571655, "sum":3}

Fuente: [Link](https://developpaper.com/how-to-use-json-encode-class-object-data-scientifically-in-php/)

Cuando use el framework/ORM en su proyecto y defina una gran cantidad de modelos, encontrará este artículo útil cuando JSON serialice estos modelos.

Puede regular el campo de salida de su interfaz, la interfaz AJAX a menudo no tendrá más campos o menos campos, el mismo campo es una cadena mientras que es una vergüenza entera.

*Epílogo*
Para datos escalares en PHP, solo los datos de punto flotante pueden desbordarse en *json_encode*. Php7 se puede configurar a través de: `serializar_precisión = -1`

Además, es posible que el navegador no admita el tipo de entero largo. Cuando el número de dígitos de ID de pedido es relativamente largo (mayor que un número entero de 32 bits), el navegador JSON. Parse() es fácil de truncar los datos. Se puede convertir en una cadena durante el procesamiento en segundo plano.

espero que sea de ayuda lo que he agregado.